# make MYSQL select more efficient

Tags: mysql

I have a Select statement that is pretty long and is only going to get longer, I am wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient, smaller.

Right now I have 128 variations of this;

```
 or search_term_1 = '$newvalue'
 or search_term_2 = '$newvalue'
 or search_term_3 = '$newvalue'
 ....
 or search_term_1 LIKE '$newvalue1%'
 or search_term_2 LIKE '$newvalue1%'
 or search_term_3 LIKE '$newvalue1%'
 ....
 or search_term_1 LIKE '$newvalue2%'
 or search_term_2 LIKE '$newvalue2%'
 or search_term_3 LIKE '$newvalue2%'
```

The **search_term_1** goes from **1-8** and then I am searching for different variations of a variable - for example "bar"

So I have it set to look for "bar", "bar ", " bar ", ",bar " and then all of these pluralized so the list is getting long. Is there a way to condense this?

Comment: The first term can be trivially changed to `'$newvalue' IN (search_term1, ..., search_termN)`. For the others, not too much you can do, since you're doing a wildcarded `like`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: yeah, but that'd capture things like "foobarbaz", which is not the same as `foo, bar, baz`

Comment: I was afraid of that, I am going to see about asserting more control over what goes into the table but was hoping that something like this was possible :: or search_term_1 LIKE '$newvalue1%' OR '$newvalue2%'

Comment: you could try something like regexes against a concatenation of those files. `where concat(field1,field2,....) regexp '$newvalue'`-type thing. but you should probably sit back and figure out if having 128 variations of a search term isn't just a symptom of a bad design, and try to come up with something a little less ...wordy.

Comment: Not really sure how to design around it. A user adds a term to their page and then I need to be able to search for the variations, so say someone is looking for "bar" and a user had added "downtown bar" or "bar, pub". I can clean the data and remove any extra punctuation so "bar, pub" becomes "bar pub". Doing that I can cut the number in half.

Comment: you should look into using a fulltext index, maybe, though it'll need some extra config because by default mysql only does 4+ letter words, not 3.

Comment: I looked into that and the site is hosted by godaddy and is a basic hostinng package, they don't allow for any modifying on the server side.

Comment: @Harkly As Marc suggested, you should check again if a fulltext index could work, it looks like a really perfect fit, since you are actually looking for full words (if I understood that correctly). If you cannot change the config value, you could use a workaround to add short words: if a user adds a short word, add a prefix to it, eg. `bar` will become `ZZZYXbar`, and add these in an additional column. Not perfect, but a fulltext index would be really fast in a lot of situations, and a fulltext search doesn't even care about different punctuation.

Comment: @Solarflare what do you mean by "add these in an additional column"? Can you send me to an example?

Comment: @harkly I meant something like this: it seems the user enters 8 search terms about himself into `search_term_xx`. You probably want to keep them as they are. For the fulltext index to work, you need transform short words into longer, so you could add `search_terms_ft`, where you (with a trigger) either add all words or only the prefixed onces (the onces that are too short). Or create `search_terms_ft_1`(to 8) and do the same. If the columns `search_term_xx` are already calculated and you don't have to display this data, you can write the prefixed words directly here.